# Listing out all the names of ASP.Net methods and mappings for a DataSet created in DataSet Designer

Tags: asp.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, tableadapter

When a typed DataSet is created using the Visual Studio DataSet Designer, several methods, etc. are generated.

Example:

```
DataSetStudentsAndParentsTableAdapters.DataTableTableAdapterStudentsAndParents
theTableAdapter.GetDataByStudentsAndParents

etc.
```

We have many DataSets created this way and it seems difficult to keep track of all names belonging to the methods and mappings.

Is there an easy way to list out all of these names for a particular DataSet created in the DataSet Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All generated classes and methods should be available to you from the Class View window. To open it from the menu: `View > Class View`.

Or you can use the Object Browser (also in the `View` menu) to see all classes and methods in your project.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and help. I'm glad the object browser lists them all together. Now I can find the names I needed.